# XslTransformException after migrating from IIS 7.0 to IIS 6.0

Tags: .net, iis, xslt

We migrated one of our websites from IIS 7.0 to IIS 6.0 and everything seemed to work fine, however we get this strange error now:

[image]

Does this issue have anything to do with this or is it - like I think - the fact that method 'GenerateSynopsis' is called with an empty parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved and the problem was a version problem in the dten600.nl -> dtSearchNetApi2.dll. I changed the api to the correct versioned api dll and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: And how do you think other people could infer that from your question? I think you should extend your question describing the problem, otherwise this is an unusefull question.